# Producing methane, reactants and products

Tags: organic-chemistry

How do I balance this reaction when producing methane using the reactants:

$$\ce{CH3COONa(s) + NaOH(s) + Ca(OH)2 -> ?}$$

The products are ***partly***

$\ce{CH4(g) + Na2CO3(s)}$

What else is missing in the products? Furthermore, how do I balance this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

$$\ce{2CH3COONa(s) + 2NaOH(s) + Ca(OH)2(s) <=> 2CH4(g) + Na2CO3(s) + CaCO3(s) + H2O}$$

You have to get same number of equal atoms in each side of the reaction (this technique is called mass balance). If there were charges, they must be balanced also.

**Example**

There are $2\times 3 + 2\times 1 + 2\,$ hydrogen atoms in left side, and there are $2\times 4 + 2$ $\ce{H}$ in the right side. So both sides give $10$ hydrogen atoms.

I hope it helps.